# null pointer when assigning drawer list adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sliding

I'm trying out to create a slide menu for android using this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) then I come up with this error, said that I have null pointer. Here are the corresponding class and logcat output [NavDrawerListAdapter class](http://pastebin.com/tCHFUMXK), [NavdrawerItem](http://pastebin.com/Tri6kP3V), and [logcat](http://pastebin.com/AWu1mdak). So far I've tried to discover what make it null and double check the tutorial, but I can't figure out any clue. I'll appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Please Share NavDrawerListAdapter.java Line No.: 51

Comment: Here it is `ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);` if comment this code, the will point to the textview just below the ImageView code

Comment: may be converview is null. debug and check please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Adapter's `getView()` method, the line:

```
if(context == null)
```

should be:

```
if(convertView == null)
```

Comment: Thank you I've made a very basic mistake.

Answer (score 1):

After going through your code and logcat...it seems you are making mistake in **getView()** method of the **NavDrawerListAdapter class**.

Inside the getView you have following mistake

***if(context == null){....*** your context cannot be null because when you are creating the Adapter you are passing the context, because of this ***convertView*** is not getting inflated with your ***R.layout.drawer_list_item***... Hence when you try ***convertView.findViewById()*** you are getting NullPointerException.

So Solution is use ***if(convertView == null)*** instead of ***if(context==null)***

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder =new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.textTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView textTitle;
    } 
}
```